# Hessian of a Matrix through Chain Rule

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, chain-rule, hessian-matrix

Given

$f= \rho u^2$

$W_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
        \rho\\
        \rho u\\
        \end{pmatrix} $
,
$W_{1p} = \begin{pmatrix}
        \rho\\
        u\\
        \end{pmatrix} $

I want to find the Hessian of $f$ with respect to $W_1$. The actual Hessian is easily found by taking one derivative after another. However, I would like to use the **product** rule and chain rule to avoid the following.

$\dfrac{\partial W_1}{\partial W_{1p}} =    \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        u & \rho \\
        \end{bmatrix} $
,
$\dfrac{\partial W_{1p}}{\partial W_{1}} 
= \left(\dfrac{\partial W_1}{\partial W_{1p}}\right)^{-1}
=  \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        -u/\rho & 1/\rho \\
        \end{bmatrix} $

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial W_{1}}
=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial W_{1p}}\dfrac{\partial W_{1p}}{\partial W_{1}}
=\begin{bmatrix}
        u^2 & 2 \rho u \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        -u/\rho & 1/\rho \\
        \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
        -u^2 & 2u \\
        \end{bmatrix} $

So far, so good, the first derivative is easily achieved. Now repeat.

$\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial W_{1}^2}
=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial W_{1}}
\left(
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial W_{1p}}\dfrac{\partial W_{1p}}{\partial W_{1}}
\right)
=\dfrac{\partial\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
        -u^2 & 2u \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\right)}{\partial W_{1}}
=\dfrac
{
\partial\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
        -u^2 & 2u \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\right)
}
{\partial W_{1p}}
\dfrac{\partial W_{1p}}{\partial W_{1}}$

$
\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial W_{1}^2}=
\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & -2u \\
        0 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        -u/\rho & 1/\rho \\
        \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
        \dfrac{2u^2}{\rho} & -\dfrac{2u}{\rho} \\
        -\dfrac{2u}{\rho} & \dfrac{2}{\rho} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

Here is my real issue. My equations are in fact much more complicated and the first derivative $\left(
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial W_{1p}}\dfrac{\partial W_{1p}}{\partial W_{1}}
\right)$ is insanely long. Each term by itself is relatively manageable so I would like to use the product rule in this way:

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial W_{1p}}
\left(
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial W_{1p}}\dfrac{\partial W_{1p}}{\partial W_{1}}
\right)
\dfrac{\partial W_{1p}}{\partial W_{1}}
=
\left(
\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial W_{1p}^2}
\dfrac{\partial W_{1p}}{\partial W_{1}}
+
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial W_{1p}}
\left(
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial W_{1p}}
\left(
\dfrac{\partial W_{1p}}{\partial W_{1}}
\right)
\right)
\right)
\dfrac{\partial W_{1p}}{\partial W_{1}}
$

Of course the above does not work (or I wouldn't be posting here).

Why am I not allowed to use the product rule?

If I am allowed, how could I do it properly?

Comment: Just figured something out from testing and probing. I need to transpose my product rule. I am still unsure why I have to do it though...

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial W_{1p}}
\left(
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial W_{1p}}\dfrac{\partial W_{1p}}{\partial W_{1}}
\right)
\dfrac{\partial W_{1p}}{\partial W_{1}}
=
\left(
\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial W_{1p}^2}
\dfrac{\partial W_{1p}}{\partial W_{1}}
+
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial W_{1p}}
\left(
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial W_{1p}}
\left(
\dfrac{\partial W_{1p}}{\partial W_{1}}
\right)
\right)
\right)^{\bold T}
\dfrac{\partial W_{1p}}{\partial W_{1}}
$

Comment: Used this to figure it out [link](http://mplab.ucsd.edu/tutorials/MatrixRecipes.pdf)